# Add USB support to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I initially loaded Ubuntu with no USB ports installed in my machine.  I have now added a USB 2.0 port to the machine but I don't know how to get Ubuntu to recognize it.  How do I get the support for USB added into the kernel?

Ubuntu 9.1

Comment: what did you do to "add a usb2.0 port to the machine"?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.1 doesn't exist... 9.10?

Comment: Yes Nathaniel, because that zero makes all the difference in determining the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do that. The kernel of Ubuntu is a fixed set of modules and all modules (which aren't already compiled into the kernel) are loaded as needed.

If your USB-Ports are not working, then there's another problem with them, and not Ubuntu not finding them.

If the port is installed right, use the `dmesg` command to see the latest messages of the system...plug in an USB-Device and check the output (or post it here or on a pastebin) of `dmesg | tail` for any clues what's wrong. If there are no messages in there regarding USB, then the ports are most likely not probably installed.

Comment: Thank you Bobby for the straight forward answer.  With a USB drive inserted I was able to use sudo fdisk -l and see the device.  One of my finer id10t moments.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the USB port isn't being recognized? Did you try plugging any USB devices into it? Most likely it's a problem with the device and not the port.

Also, how did you add the port? Is this a desktop, and you added a PCI or PCIe card?